# Problem With Perturbation Theory of Klein-Gordon Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, perturbation-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I have a confusion regarding the perturbative correction to the Klein-Gordon field in the presence of interactions (e.g. a potential).

Consider a theory in which the equation of motion is given by
$$
\Box \,\phi = - V'(\phi) \, , \qquad \text{where} \ V(\phi) = \frac{\lambda}{n!} \, \phi^n \, .
$$
By expanding the field $\phi$ with respect to the perturbative parameter $\lambda$ as
$$
\phi = \phi_0 + \delta \phi_1 + \cdots \, ,
$$
I would like to solve for the first-order correction $\delta \phi_1(x)$.

In the Heisenberg picture, the field evolves as
$$
\dot{\phi} = -i [\phi, H] \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dot{\phi}_0 + \dot{\delta \phi}_1 = -i [ \phi_0 + \delta \phi_1, H_0 + H_1] \, ,
$$
where
$$
H_1(t) = \frac{\lambda}{n!} \int d^3 y \, \phi^n (t, \vec{y})
$$
is the interaction Hamiltonian.
Solving the Heisenberg equation iteratively, we get at order $\lambda$
$$
\delta \phi_1 (x) = \frac{-i \lambda}{n!} \int_{-\infty}^{x^0} dT \int d^3 y \, [\phi_0(T, \vec{x}), \phi_0^n (T, \vec{y})] = 0 \, , 
$$
which **VANISHES(!!)** due to the equal-time commutation relation.

On the other hand, if we instead solve the field equation itself iteratively
$$
\Box \, \delta \phi_1 (x) = -V' (\phi_0)
$$
using the retarded Green's function $G_R (x, y) = i \Theta(x^0 - y^0) [ \phi_0(x), \phi_0(y)]$, we get a **non-vanishing result** (which I think is the correct one):
\begin{align}
\delta \phi_1(x) &= \frac{-\lambda}{(n - 1)!} \int d^4 y \, G_R(x, y) \phi_0^{n - 1}(y) \\
&= \frac{-i \lambda}{(n - 1)!} \int_{-\infty}^{x^0} dy^0 \, \int d^3 y \, [ \phi_0(x), \phi_0(y)] \phi_0^{n - 1} (y) \neq 0 \, ,
\end{align}
the reason being that the fields inside the commutator are now NOT at equal times.

My question is why did I end up with such a discrepancy?
Am I missing something?